# openapi-generator-cli, c# customize properties and types names generated for oneOf requestBodies and polymorphic properties

Tags: java, c#, typescript, openapi, openapi-generator

I have an api with some complex DTOs with polymorphic properties and some and points which accept polymorphic request bodies (`oneOf`).

Something like the following:

**Example c# complex type**

```cs
namespace Sample {

    public class ComplexType
    {
        public PolymorphicTypeBase PolymorphicProperty { get; set; }
    }

    public abstract class PolymorphicTypeBase {
        public string SomeSharedProperty { get; set; }
    }

    public class PolymorphicSubtypeA : PolymorphicTypeBase
    {
        public string PropertyA { get; set; }
    }

    public class PolymorphicSubtypeB : PolymorphicTypeBase
    {
        public string PropertyB { get; set; }
    }

}
```

The openapi spec for those types looks like this:

```json
...
{
  "ComplexType" : {
    "type" : "object", 
    "properties" : {
      "polymorphicProperty" : {
          "oneOf": [
            { "$ref": "#/components/schemas/PolymorphicTypeA" },
            { "$ref": "#/components/schemas/PolymorphicTypeB" }
          ],
          "nullable": true
      }
    }
  },
  "PolymorphicTypeBase": {
    "required": ["discriminator"],
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
      "discriminator": {
        "type": "string",
        "nullable": true
      },
      "someSharedProperty": {
        "type": "string",
        "nullable": true
      },
    },
    "additionalProperties": false,
    "discriminator": {
      "propertyName": "discriminator",
      "mapping": {
        "PolymorphicTypeA": "#/components/schemas/PolymorphicTypeA",
        "PolymorphicTypeB": "#/components/schemas/PolymorphicTypeB",
      }
    }
  },
  "PolymorphicTypeA" : {
    "type": "object",
    "allOf": [
      {
        "$ref": "#/components/schemas/PolymorphicTypeBase"
      }
    ],
    "properties": {
      "propertyA": {
        "type": "string",
        "nullable": true
      }
    },
    "additionalProperties": false
  },
  "PolymorphicTypeB" : {
    "type": "object",
    "allOf": [
      {
        "$ref": "#/components/schemas/PolymorphicTypeBase"
      }
    ],
    "properties": {
      "propertyB": {
        "type": "string",
        "nullable": true
      }
    },
    "additionalProperties": false
  }
}
...
```

##### THE PROBLEM

I'd like `openapi-generator-cli` to produce models in the client library that look like `ComplexType`, where the `PolymorphicProperty` is of type `PolymorphicTypeBase` (which is present in generated models), what I'm getting instead is an additional type called `ComplexTypePolymorphicProperty`, which has all the annotations for know subtypes, but `PolymorphicTypeBase` is not referenced anywhere. I guess this happens because in the openapi spec the information about the base type (`PolymorphicTypeBase`) gets lost.

##### Question

Is there any way to reference the base type in the openapi-spec?

Is there a way to customize the type and properties names produced by the `c#`, `typescript-angular` and `java` generators?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved my problem implementing custom schema and request body filters that replace the `oneOf` definitions for existing components with references (`$ref`)